# javascript or mootools way to animate scrollTop like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

What is the equivalent of this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 200
}, 400);
```

In MooTools or agnostic javascript?

Im going round in circles....

Cheers

Comment: Have you even tried this?

1. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animate+scroll+%5Bmootools%5D
2. http://www.google.com/search?q=animate+scroll+mootools

Answer (score 2):

This loop can animate the scrollTop property of the window in basic javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var offset = 0; //vertical offset
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, offset);
        offset += 4; // plus 4 pixels
        if (offset >= 200) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 8); //  200px/4px==50 cycles ; 400ms/50cycles == 8ms per cycle
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJLjb/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you asked for a version in mootools, it's just one line:

```
new Fx.Scroll(window).start(0, 200);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ye3vX/

Note: It needs mootools more's Fx.Scroll.